# "of" is preventing TypeScript from highlighting mistakes when returning my object

Tags: typescript, rxjs

While creating some mock data I've noticed that, when returning an observable of any custom object, TypeScript is not telling me anything if I enter a property that is not part of the object.

My object:

```
export interface ValidationObject {
  valid: boolean;
  message?: {
    errorCode: string;
    translatedErrors: {
      [key: string]: string;
    };
  };
}
```

When I return a ValidationObject object directly with a wrong property like this:

```
  public returnValidationFn(): ValidationObject {
    return {
      valid: true,
      unknownProperty: 'test'
    }
  }
```

TypeScript is highlighting the unknownProperty, saying
`TS2322: Type '{ valid: true; unknownProperty: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidationObject'.`, which is what I want.

But if I have a case where I have to return an Observable of my ValidationObject and, by mistake, add some wrong property like this:

```
  public returnValidationFn(): Observable<ValidationObject> {
    return of({
      valid: true,
      unknownProperty: 'test'
    })
  }
```

TypeScript isn't complaining about anything. Surely it is something that has to do with the operator `of` but I was wondering if someone has an explanation for this?

Comment: `of({ valid: true, unknownProperty: 'test' })` _is_ an `Observable<ValidationObject>`. It has the only required property, of the correct type, and the other one's inaccessible through the relevant interface anyway. In the other case you get _excess property checks_, rather than letting TS infer the type. You can force these with `of<ValidationObject>({ /* ... */ });`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your fast answer! Forcing does the trick but I'm unsure that I understood well.
Basically, since my `Observable<ValidationObject>` is returned with the required property (valid), it does not care about the rest unlike a simple return of a `ValidationObject`? Why this different behavior between them? But indeed if I add every properties, I'll get the excess property check.

Comment: For explanation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#object-literals-are-open-ended

Comment: It's saying that it's ignoring if it's a .js file but does not explain anything about the fact that returning an observable of my custom object is not letting TS scanning of wrong properties. Both are returning the only required property of the correct type. But TS does its job only when it's not an observable and I'm trying to find the reason.